# Position of Desktop Icon in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, shortcut-file

A friend of mine would like a program that can 'remember' positions of certain shortcuts on his desktop and restore those at the click of a button. I said that it would probably not be too hard to code that, but after a rather long period of time spent googling, I haven't found out where desktop icon positions are stored.

So, my question: How and where does Windows 7 remember the position of icons on the desktop?

Comment: The question is about Windows OS behaviour, not about programming. Therefore 'programming language' is irrelevant. Arguably, the question itself is borderline off-topic also.

Comment: Jonners is right. I checked the FAQ, though, which didn't sound too restrictive. I also thought that stackoverflow is still the best place to ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulating the positions of desktop icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964260/manipulating-the-positions-of-desktop-icons)