# Manipulating the positions of desktop icons

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop

I am currently trying to retrieve the list of icons from my desktop to change their locations and / or hide them as well as display others.

I tried to get the `FolderView` in the code below but it doesn't even show the number of icons I have on the desktop because `count` return **0**.

```
HWND hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
HWND hDefView = FindWindowEx(hDesktop, NULL, L"SHELLDLL_DefView", NULL);
HWND folderView = FindWindowEx(hShellWnd, NULL, L"SysListView32", NULL);

int count = (int) SendMessage(folderView, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
cout << count << endl;
```

I did tests on the variables and is noticed that `hDefView` is `NULL`.
Probably the reason why `count` return **0**.

**EDIT :**  After replace `GetDesktopWindow` by `GetShellWindow` the result is always the same, **0**

Comment: Actually you should open Desktop folder and enumerate files there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the window handle of the desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669111/how-do-i-get-the-window-handle-of-the-desktop)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate because this post doesn't help me. @VTT I want to get the icons count for hide icons later.

Comment: @VTT Icons come from virtual locations **and** two different filesystem folders.

Comment: @VTT Things like `Computer`, `Recycle Bin`, etc. show as icons but are not present in the folder

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211122-00/?p=105948
There is an Old New Thing article on this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell window hierarchy is not documented nor stable. "ProgMan" is usually the parent of "SHELLDLL_DefView" but if you change to slideshow wallpaper it can also be "WorkerW".

It is much better to [inspect/manipulate the desktop with the documented shell COM interfaces](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933): [`IShellWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836568(v=vs.85).aspx), `IShellBrowser`, `IFolderView` and `IShellFolder`.

Comment: It would help if you included the important interfaces in this answer.