# Where are Windows desktop icon positions stored?

Tags: windows, icons

Where does Windows 10 store the position of desktop icons? Are they in the registry somewhere?

By position I mean that when you drag them around and reboot they remain in the place you put them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulating the positions of desktop icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964260/manipulating-the-positions-of-desktop-icons)